# Accents aren't print after UTF encoding/decoding

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, inputstream, bufferedreader

I've read [several](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) [articles](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com.es/2009/05/java-rough-guide-to-character-encoding.html) on the whole [topic](http://unicode.org/faq/) and I still don't understand what's going on here. Please, see for yourselves in the following working example (actually, no example, this is the complete class I'm working on with some added `main()`).

```
public class Console extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2260047176466126845L;
    private static final String ENCODING = "UTF-8";

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> inBuffer = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer>();
    private JTextArea display = new JTextArea();
    private JTextField input = new JTextField();
    private ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Input: " + input.getText());
            byte[] bytes = (input.getText() + "\n").getBytes(Charset.forName(ENCODING));
            input.setText("");
            System.out.println("Bytes: " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
            for(byte b : bytes) {
                inBuffer.offer((int) b);
            }
        }
    };

    public Console() {
        super("Debugging");

        LayoutManager layout = new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        setLayout(layout);
        display.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(420, 210));
        display.setEditable(false);
        input.addActionListener(listener);
        input.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(420, 20));
        add(display);
        add(input);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(
                    new InputStream() {

                        boolean lastWasEnd = false;

                        @Override
                        public int read() throws IOException {
                            Integer c;
                            if(lastWasEnd) {
                                lastWasEnd = false;
                                return -1;
                            }

                            try {
                                c = inBuffer.poll(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                                lastWasEnd = inBuffer.isEmpty();
                                return c;
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            return -1;
                        }
                    }, Charset.forName(ENCODING)
            )
    );

    public final PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            display.append(Character.toString((char) b));
        }

    });

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Console cons = new Console();
        cons.out.println(">> Console started. Using charset: " + Charset.forName(ENCODING));
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Loop");
            try {
                cons.out.println(">> " + cons.in.readLine());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It all goes well until I try to write any character over the standard ASCII range, such as but not limited to `áéíóúñ`. In those cases I get *missing character squares* instead. I've tried using other encodings to no avail.

UPDATE:

Some specific questions:

1. Why doesn't specifying a Charset in `InputStreamReader`'s constructor make it decode properly multibyte characters.
2. `InputStream`s sometimes receive characters longer than one byte. How do they recognize and process those characters anyway.

UPDATE 2:

I had completely forgot about this piece of code:

```
@Override
public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    display.append(Character.toString((char) b));
}
```

Which was causing the trouble. I will rewrite it properly and expect to have no further encoding/decoding problems.

Comment: Change the `BlockingQueue<Integer>`to `BlockingQueue<Character>`

Comment: A conversion to bytes must be done in order to use `InputStream.read()` and at that time I'll be facing the same problem again! (I think...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 is a multi-byte encoding. That means that one character might have a representation that is more than one byte long, especially if it is not a US-ASCII kind of character. You are specifically decomposing the string into bytes for reasons that are not clear, and appending them. So you are disassembling these characters into individual bytes and then treating these bytes as if they are whole characters.

If the character is more than one byte long this will just not work.

Consider why you are trying to enqueue the individual bytes and not whole characters and if there is not a good reason then try not converting the string to bytes but rather characters.

Comment: I wanted the interactive console to provide some kind of "standard" I/O in the way that calls to `System.in` and `System.out` work. With that in mind I tried to use a `PrintStream` for output and an `InputStream` conveniently wrapped inside a `BufferedReader` for input. I had to define some way to route everything from my `JTextField` to an `InputSteam.read()` which returns bytes one by one.

Comment: I assumed that decoding those bytes was automagically done in the `InputStreamReader(InputStream, Charset)` code but it appears that it's not. I also tried to use UTF-16 with that charset so two bytes would mandatorily be used for decoding, but buggy behavior remained unchaged.

Comment: Ok, I had totally forgot about the `.append()`. I went crazy rewriting the input part and the output was the problem the whole time. I'm marking yours as the accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I ended up implementing a basic buffered `OutputStream.write()` like the following and now all I/O works fine.

Here's what I wrote to fix the output. I'd like to improve endline (`'\n'`) detection so it doesn't look so hackish but I haven't found a suitable solution for this right now so comparing with 10 will do.

```
public final PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
    private ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException {

        buffer.put((byte) b);
        if(b == 10) {
            buffer.flip();
            String output = decoder.decode(buffer).toString();
            display.append(output);
            buffer.clear();
        }
    }
});
```